# jquery Flot find out if series has been clicked

Tags: jquery, flot

Assuming I have the following data (obviously there is some abstraction with the date in this example) plotted using flot:
[[6:40 AM, 0.5],[6:50 AM, 0.5]]

6:40 AM - leftmost plot
6:45 AM -middle plot
6:50 AM - rightmost plot

Picture:
[image]

I want to be able to listen to a "plotclick" event and be able to figure out if the series was clicked between two datapoint (ie. 6:45 AM).

I know I can do:

elem.bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, item) {
}

But I don't know how I can figure out  whether I clicked on an actual point that plot interpolated (see middle graph from picture above).

Anyone have an idea how I can figure whether I clicked on an interpolated point from the series

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you make the bind function, you can use

```
item.datapoint[0]
```

to find the x position where you clicked. You can use that to compare with other x-coordinates on the graph. I don't believe it will give you a date. It will simply give you the x position of the click, which in your case, could actually make the comparison simpler.